# Cart Price Rules

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules

How do I create a shopping cart price rule,  I want to sell wallpaper samples so that if the customer buys 1, 2 or 3 the price would be the same.  I have tried selecting 'If all these conditions are true' 'quantity in cart is equal to or less than 3' and the attribute is 'sample' then the price is 1.50  which works fine provided the quantity 2 or 3 selected is the same SKU.  If I add two different sample sku's to the cart they both have the attribute 'sample' attached but the shopping cart rule does not work becasue they are different SKU's?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

This should work if you add the `sample` attribute to `Conditions` and `Quantity in cart  equals or less than 3` to `Actions > Apply rule to...`